# What exactly is the sh command?

Tags: linux, debian, sh

I can't figure out what the sh command is?

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh

Does it execute a file?

like in tomcat:

```
sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Sorry, just confused.

Comment: @Chopper3: tags aren't for expressing your opinion, comments are.

Comment: "In Ubuntu 6.10, the default system shell, `/bin/sh`, was changed to `dash` (the Debian Almquist Shell); previously it had been `bash` (the GNU Bourne-Again Shell)."—https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh . `dash` is a little quicker than `bash`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

sh is the [bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

There are several shells, of which bourne is the old standard, installed on all unix systems, and generally the one you can guarantee will exist.

The shell is the command interpreter that takes your input, provides output back to the screen, to the correct files, etc, and provides all the basic built-in commands you need to manage jobs, kill, test expressions, etc.

Your command above is saying to run that shell-script using the bourne shell. Different shells use different syntax, so using the correct shell is a requirement. The first line of the shell should also define which to use: #!/bin/sh says use /bin/sh

Comment: On many systems (like in Mac OS X), nowadays `sh` is actually `bash`, aka the Bourne-again shell. The command `sh --version` will tell one more. It's backwards compatible with the Bourne shell though.

Answer (score 10):

sh is the bourne shell. `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` is a shell script.  `sh file` runs `file` as a shell script.  generally one would just set the execute bit and run `./file`.

Comment: ok so I am going out and changing my shell implicitly to run that command, ok thanks.

Comment: Techinically, you would be changing the script.

Make sure the first line is:

#!/bin/bash

then:

chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

to make it executable